# Overriding toSting in derived class

Tags: c#, overriding, abstract-class, tostring

I have an abstract class `Animal` Looking like this

```
abstract class Animal{
    protected int numberOfPaws;

    public abstract String speak();

    public String toString(){
        return "I have " + numberOfPaws + " paws";
    }
}
```

Then I have a derived class that has a new implementation of `toString()` looking like this

```
class Cow : Animal{
    public Cow : base(4) {}

    public override String speak(){
        return "Moo!";
    }

    public new Strinf toString(){
        return "I am a Cow " + base.toString();
    }
}
```

And I have a main looking like this

```
void Main{
    Cow c = new Cow();

    Console.WriteLine(c.toString());
}
```

But when I run this it prints `UserQuery+Cow` to the console.

I have no clue as to what i'm doing wrong? Is it doing this beacause of the `base.toString()`?

Comment: Firstly since You are using interface, You should change Your cow initialization to Cow c = new Animal();

Comment: @MajkeloDev No, it should be `Animal c = new Cow();`.

Comment: Remember, that all C# objects (include classes) have `ToString` method, use it and enjoy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `override` keyword:

```
abstract class Animal
{
    protected int numberOfPaws;

    public abstract String speak();

    public override string ToString(){
        return "I have " + numberOfPaws + " paws";
    }
}

class Cow : Animal
{
    public Cow : base(4) {}

    public override String speak(){
        return "Moo!";
    }

    public override string ToString(){
        return "I am a Cow " + base.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: if I do `public override String toString()` in `Animal` it gives an error saying that it cant find a suitable method to override

Comment: `ToString`, not `toString`

Answer (score 2):

You should read here : [How To: Override the ToString Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173154%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

```
public override string ToString() 
{
    return "I have " + numberOfPaws + " paws";
}
```

You miss the `override` keyword